# Optional group with PSToogleSwitch

Tags: iphone, settings, appsettings

I'd like to have a settings bundle behavior similar to the iPhone WiFi settings.
If you select the toggle switch and set it to on, an optional group with the specific settings appears. How is this done? I haven't found any clue by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a preferences bundle yourself (jailbreak-level), you can dynamically add and remove PSSpecifiers in your switch's "set" selector. If this is for an App Store application, I do not believe that is possible (in which case, I would suggest attempting to integrate these preferences into your application, where you have code-level control over their display and setup.)